# Table namespace not ready yet, try again later

Tags: hbase

Getting below error while creating a table in Hbase. Can some one please help me with this. Thank you

> java.io.IOException: Table Namespace Manager not ready yet, try again
>   later
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.getNamespaceDescriptor(HMaster.java:3387)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1829)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1965)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:40470)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2078)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:108)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FifoRpcScheduler$1.run(FifoRpcScheduler.java:74)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

These type of errors will come when it cant able to find block locations.

Please check Hbase region server log carefully.

We faced same issue. and got this fixed with

```
hbase hbck -fix
```

It will find out inconsistencies of hbase and it will fix
Also , Please check [this](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/hbck.in.depth.html) for more details.

***If nothing works for you final step is hbase restart***

Comment: Tried using hbase hbck which showed 3 inconsitencies.

META region or some of its attributes are null.
hbase:meta, replicaId 0 is not found on any region.
hbase:meta table is not consistent. Run HBCK with proper fix options to fix hbase:meta inconsistency.
Tried using - fix but ended up with error after reaching max retries.

Comment: @shivanagesh: There are several other options with hbck which are listed here in detail please try these. You can also fix individual region-level inconsistencies separately, rather than fixing them automatically with the -fix argument http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/admin_hbck_poller.html

Comment: pls keep posted. if nothing works for you final step is hbase restart which is extreme.. :-)

Comment: I have resolved the inconsistencies with 3 steps
1) Stopping the HBase
2) Clearing the Zookeeper data related to Hbase
3) Starting the Hbase.